# EXCEL - Count participant name (only when all race activities complete)

Tags: excel, count, dcount

Thanks for your attention:

I have an ultra-marathon scenario with multiple contestants each competing in multiple events (i.e. swim, cycle, run).

I need a little help on the formula to only count the participants when they have completed all three activities.

I have tried DCOUNT& ARRAY formulas without success (wondering if there is a non-VBA solution?)

.

Column A = names, Column B = activities

[ Andy - 
Swim  ]

[ Andy -
Run  ]

[ Andy  -
Cycle ]

[ Brent  -
Swim  ]

[ Brent  -
Run  ]

[ Brent  -
Cycle  ]

.

Many Thanks,
Stu.

Comment: I would suggest structuring your data. For instance, have column A house the names and have each column to the right (B, C, D, etc) house one particular activity. This task becomes very simple then.

Answer (score 0):

Value in C4, assuming data starts on row 2, is sorted by name, paste all the way down:

`=if(AND(A2=A3=A4),1,0)`

Then, a sum or countif function at the bottom of the column.